# Show loading property on Pageload with nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project that is working well. However on the loading of the page a async method is performed.

```
import charge from '~plugins/charge'
export default {
    asyncData (context, callback) {
        const subscription = context.params.id;
        charge.getAll(subscription, function(result){
            let data = result.data;;
            callback(null, data)
        });
    }
}
```

My Problem is, that the page stays with until the async operation has been performed. How can i Show a loader until the function returns a result?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51270636/104380

Answer (score 0):

There is an official example in Nuxt.js repo. Check out the [Custom-Loading](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/custom-loading) example.