# Nuxt.js: Start loading indicator from vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

According to documentation, there is a way to manually start the nuxt loading indicator in a component as such:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        startLoading() {
            this.$root.$loading.start();
        },
    },
}
```

Is there any way to toggle the loader from a vuex action? How can I access the `$root` object from a vuex action?

Answer (score 7):

Sweet! Apparently it can be accessed through the `window` property which is available on client. It would be advisable to confirm that the action is run on the client, not on server, by checking `process.browser`:

```
export const actions = {
    startLoading({ commit }) {
        if (process.browser) {
            window.$nuxt.$root.$loading.start();
        }
        commit('SET_LOADING', true);
    },
    finishLoading({ commit }) {
        if (process.browser) {
            window.$nuxt.$root.$loading.finish();
        }
        commit('SET_LOADING', false);
    },
}
```

Pretty cool. The actions are called from axios interceptors, so now it indicates loading globally when making any request to the server.

Comment: There could be multiple things loading, each finishes at different time. How can you tell which has finished when?

Comment: @vsync if you want to provide this feedback to the user: "many things are loading and you have to wait..." you probably want to: add a loading state in different components or wrap those calls in a single `Array` of `Promise`s and await to `Promise.all([...promises])`

Answer (score 0):

I am using `layouts/default.vue` file to check if current process is server-side or client-side.
Example:

```
<template>
  <div class="fontFamily">
    <Nuxt v-if="isClient" />
    <div v-else class="container">
        <img class="logo" src="~/assets/images/logo-hori.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isClient: false
        }
    },
    beforeMount () {
        this.isClient = false
    },
    mounted() {
        this.isClient = true
    }
}
</script>
```

If it is in server side, I return logo of app, and then return app if in client side. You can access store as well after mounted